# Sending Shapefile to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: shapefile, c#, sql-server, open-source-gis

How can I send a shapefile to an SQL Server table?

I have searched and found a tool called [ShapetoSQL](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/shape2sql) but I am developing a c# Windows application so I am looking for an Open Source solution.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What research have you done prior to asking the question?  Where are you stuck?  The first result from a Google search yielded an answer that may be useful for you: http://topherlandry.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/gis-how-to-check-a-shapefiles-data-in-c/.  Please refer to the help center for advice on how to ask a "good" question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Aaron I have edit the question. Now can you please answer it?

Comment: did you found any solution to import shape file to sqlserver 2012 ?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [SharpMap](https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/). It's a GPL spatial library for .NET C#.

> SharpMap is an easy-to-use mapping library for use in web and desktop
>   applications. It provides access to many types of GIS data, enables 
>   spatial querying of that data, and  renders beautiful maps. The engine
>   is written in C# and based on the .Net 4.0 framework. SharpMap is
>   released under GNU Lesser General Public License.